# If statement not working - what is wrong with this syntax?

Tags: xcode, if-statement

I get an "Expected Identifier" message against the if line. Any ideas why?

```
    if ([inputA.text isEqualToString:@""]) && ([inputB.text <> isEqualToString:@""]) { 
        c = 1;
    }
```

I'm trying to say it both inputs are empty...
I presume there isn't an easier way to say if the text is null in Obj C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` statement requires that its condition expression be enclosed in parentheses.  You have a compound expression.  You've used parentheses around the subexpressions of the logical AND operation (&&), but you haven't surrounded the entire expression in parentheses.  (The subexpressions don't actually require parentheses in this case, but they don't hurt.)

Next, you have a random `<>` in the second subexpression.  What is that doing in there?  In some languages that is the "not equal" operator, but a) it's not an operator in C or Objective-C, b) it wouldn't go inside a message-send expression like that, and c) you claim you were trying to check that both inputs are empty, so I wouldn't expect you to try to negate the test for equality with the empty string.

So, fixing just those problems yields:

```
if ([inputA.text isEqualToString:@""] && [inputB.text isEqualToString:@""]) { 
    c = 1;
}
```

That said, pie's answer is good, too. It also works if either of the inputs has a `nil` text property, too.

Comment: Apologies for such a basic mistake. A little too many trees from the wood syndrome and not enough time reading C. Yes that works perfectly and now understand the parenthesising hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([inputA.text length]==0 && [inputB.text length]==0)
{     
    c = 1;
}
```